# How to do a integration in for loop in parallel in python to run in a CLUSTER

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, mpi

I am completely new to parallel computing, in fact, never wrote a code myself other that running some available codes (written on C++) on the cluster. Please be considerate! I am trying to run a `for` loop in parallel on a cluster to do a integration n-times. A prototype of what I want is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

f = lambda z, y, x: a*(x*y*z)

a = np.linspace(1,1000,100)

out = np.zeros(100)

for i, ai in enumerate(a):
    a = ai
    out[i] = integrate.tplquad(f, 1, 2, lambda x: 2, lambda x: 3,lambda x, y: 0, lambda x, y: 1)[0]
    print(ai, out[i])
```

and typically I run my jobs as (a PBS script):

```
mpirun -np 50 python myscript.py > output.txt
```

My idea is that I would run each loop simultaneously, say 100 loop on 50 processors twice for faster computation! I don't know if this the way parallel jobs run on a cluster or not but I am trying to learn. Please help!

Note: I am using python 3. I have installed `mpi4py` and `multiprocess` with a hope that they will be useful but could not implement anything beyond this.

My computational knowledge of python is at the level of Newman's Computational Physics. It would be very helpful for me if you kindly provide some additional references on parallel computation.